# update multiple table with the same trigger DB Oracle

Tags: oracle, database-trigger, maximo

i'm creating a trigger, for ibm maximo application, that has to start when the field mens_ack is updated;
when that happens, the 'status' field must become of a certain value

after that i have to update another table (longdescription table) based on the relationship workorderid=ldkey

```
create or replace TRIGGER "MAXIMO"."CHANGE_MENS_MAINT_T" 
AFTER UPDATE OF MENS_ACK ON WORKORDER
BEGIN
    update workorder
    set status='SCHED', statusdate= sysdate
    where mens_ack='1' and status!='SCHED';

    update longdescription 
    set ldtext= concat(ldtext, 'scheduled maintenance - '+sysdate+' ')
    where ldkey = ????;
END;
```

I can't use NEW and OLD in this trigger, so i doesn't know how to take the WORKORDERID (the key on which the relation is based) in order to specify what record i have to find in longdescription table

can anyone help me?

Comment: Why does it need to be an after-statement trigger, rather than a for-each-row trigger?

Comment: Ooh. A status update via SQL. I have dealt with enough problems from this, that I hate to see it. Various bits of business logic are being skipped this way, most notably the status history table. Just throwing my not-very-helpful thoughts out there. I'm sure you are stuck with this scenario so you can't change the SQL (though you could maybe make your trigger comprehensive enough to replicate a good amount of it).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the RETURNING INTO clause from the first update.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/returninginto_clause.htm

```
update workorder
set status='SCHED', statusdate= sysdate
where mens_ack='1' and status!='SCHED'
returning workorderid into v_workorderid;
```

Watch out for the number of updated workorders, since the v_workorderid might have to be declared as an array.